# my.cnf parameter optimization

Tags: query-performance, innodb, optimization, mysql-8.0

Looking for an optimized my.cnf configuration. And more importantly, I am actually looking for the relation between these parameter/system variable and my system's memory. So, if server's memory increases, I know which variables' value to tweak.
These variables are

```
innodb_log_buffer_size

sort_buffer_size

read_buffer_size

read_rnd_buffer_size

join_buffer_size

thread_stack

binlog_cache_size

innodb_open_files       

open_files_limit        

table_open_cache
```

Now, to be clear, in all my studying, I only found some model values for these variables, but no explanation related with system hardware. It kinda feels like these variables are often not talked about. But, I really need these relations and justification to edit (or not edit) these variables.
Btw, if anyone is wondering what's wrong with default values, I should say the system I am looking to design won't be handled with default values. There are Millions of data, hundreds of tables which would be joined, sorted and whatnot.

MySQL is running on 12 GB of RAM and 4 Core CPU

Answer (score 0):

That's a huge topic.

And it is *mostly* not worth pursuing.

If `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is about 70% of RAM (8GB on your server), you can *mostly* ignore everything else in the configuration.

- `open_files_limit` comes from the OS; you can't really change it.
- `thread_stack` is code dependant; do not change.
- `max_connections` (default 151) affects many of the settings because most (of the ones you listed) are "per connection".
- Do not arbitrarily raise settings (without some specific query that needs it) -- else you could run out of RAM, leading to swapping.  Swapping is much worse than having a setting that is too small.

For a deeper analysis, http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning

When you find a query that is running too slow, here are the likely things to change, in order:

1. indexing
2. formulation of the query
3. whether you really need the query
4. my.cnf
5. hardware

Note that the `my.cnf` far down that list.  That is, focus on queries not once config.